# How do I get my header to align with my navigation bar at the center of my page?

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

I'm very new to HTML and CSS. I'm trying to center two objects - my header image and my navigation

this is my header CSS

```
div #header-img {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: -30px;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }
```

this is my header html code

```
<div id="header-img">
    <img src="http://metaphorcontrol.com/solewebsite/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/SoleHeaders1.jpg">
    </div>
```

I was wondering how I could also align it with the following items from the html code below.

```
<div>
        <nav><ul>
            <li style="background-color: #99042A;"><a href="/food-wine.html">Fine Foods</a></li>
            <li style="background-color: #585123;"><a href="/wine-cellar.html">Wine & Cellar</a></li>
            <li style="background-color: #2E0219;"><a href="/kitchenware.html">Kitchenware</a></li>
            <li style="background-color: #211103;"><a href="/our-philosophy.html">Our Philosophy</a></li>
            <li style="background-color: #DBCCC5;"><a href="/register.html">Register</a>|<a href="/login.html">Log-In</a></li>
        </ul></nav>
    </div>
```

with the following CSS

```
    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        overflow: visible;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: -4px;
            }

        nav li {
            float: left;
            width: 204px;
            height: 80px;
            overflow: hidden; 
            white-space: nowrap;
            }
```

Where in the syntax did I go wrong and what should I keep in mind in the future to ensure all the behaviors I want are correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/xobiyeqifu/edit?html,css

Comment: http://output.jsbin.com/xobiyeqifu/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your nav has padding on it, and the image does not. It is pushing it over and causing it not to line up to the left like the image is.

```
nav ul {
  padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: visible;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -4px;
        }
```

Add the padding to the top part and they will line up. You can use the position: and create an outer div with a set width to contain the elements and with the margins set to auto they should center correctly within it as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to add position:relative to both

```
 div #header-img {
            position:relative;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: -30px;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

And to access the #header-img div "directly" I'm guessing your purpose is  to do this?

```
div#header-img { /* CSS HERE */ }
```

...not

```
div #header-img { /* CSS HERE */ }
```

Probably works anyway since your site is probably surrounded by at least one div, though :) But the difference is :

**div#header-img** = a div with ID header-img

**div #header-img** = an element with ID header-img inside a div (which ever div, really)...

You make the choice, simply! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at bootstrap... It seems it is fast becoming the standard for base design.

It comes with responsive and pre-styled classes. 
The nav bar that is provided by bootstrap can very easily fit your need.

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/) is a basic outline for what bootstrap is and the download.

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) is the full tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a width in your header and your nav and regarding your header-img, `display:block` instead of inline-block

```css
   body{width:100%;}
#wrapper{width:1024px;
   margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}
   
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0!important;
    padding:0!important;
     
        }

    nav li {
        float:left;
      text-align:center;
        width: 204px;
        height: 80px;
        overflow: hidden; 
        white-space: nowrap;
        }

   #header-img {
   
 display:block;
    margin-top: -30px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header-img">
<img src="http://metaphorcontrol.com/solewebsite/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/SoleHeaders1.jpg">
</div>
<div>
    <nav><ul>
        <li style="background-color: #99042A;"><a href="/food-wine.html">Fine Foods</a></li>
        <li style="background-color: #585123;"><a href="/wine-cellar.html">Wine & Cellar</a></li>
        <li style="background-color: #2E0219;"><a href="/kitchenware.html">Kitchenware</a></li>
        <li style="background-color: #211103;"><a href="/our-philosophy.html">Our Philosophy</a></li>
        <li style="background-color: #DBCCC5;"><a href="/register.html">Register</a>|<a href="/login.html">Log-In</a></li>
    </ul></nav>
</div>  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```